# How to stop displaying images in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

Hi I am new to I phone programming. Can anybody tell me using below code I am displaying an `UIImage` one by one automatically using below code. Here all `UIImages` I am storing in `NSArray` once all `UIImages` display it have stop but here how can i stop that once all `UIImages` finish.

```
- (void)displayPicture{
    for (NSString* path in array000) { 
        [blaukypath2 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",path); 
    } 

    NSLog(@"%@",blaukypath2); 
    NSLog(@"%icurrentImage DIDF",currentImage); 

    currentImage++; 
    if (currentImage >= blaukypath2.count) currentImage = 0; 

    UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage]; 
    [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag]; 
    NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);
}
```

Comment: Is this inside a function, a loop or what? Because this code actually executes once

Comment: Acctually here iam image +audio i am display once audio finesh inside the did finesh playing method i am call

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a UIImage, the simplest thing that  you could do this:

```
myUIImage = nil;
```

make sure myUIImage is hooked up in your `storyboard` or `xib` file, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly how your code is working, but if it is in some kind of `for` or `while` loop, these lines might be your problem:

```
currentImage++; 
if (currentImage >= blaukypath2.count) currentImage = 0;
```

You are incrementing `currentImage`, but when you get to the last image in `blaukypath2`, you are setting `currentImage` to 0 and starting all over again. Try this instead:

```
if (currentImage < blaukypath2.count)
{
    currentImage++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the incrementation of `currentImage` is done no matter what. Make sure it is done only when you're still in the loop of your array `blaukypath2`. The image `img10` should also only be displayed when you're still in that loop.

```
if (currentImage < blaukypath2.count) {

    UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage]; 
    [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag]; 
    NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);

    currentImage++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code.

1 - You should move image initialisation loop from 'did finish playing method',
because it is profusely. You need to do that once in some initialisation method.
In the same place you need initialize currentImage as zero.

2 - To display each image only one time you need following code in 'did finish playing method'

```
if (currentImage < blaukypath2.count) {
    UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage]; 
    [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag]; 
    NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);
    currentImage++;
} else {
    [img10 setImage:nil]; 
    NSLog(@"all images was displayed DIDF");
}
```